# Access the R deriv .grad

Tags: r, derivative

Hej

I am trying to get access to .grad[, "x"] <- 2 * x from: (this is an example, obviously)

```
deriv(~ x^2,"x")
>expression({
>.value <- x^2
>.grad <- array(0, c(length(.value), 1L), list(NULL, c("x")))
>.grad[, "x"] <- 2 * x
>attr(.value, "gradient") <- .grad
>.value
>})
```

how do I do this It's tiresome to copy and paste and surely not intended

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd be better off with `D()`:

```
D(expression(x^2),"x")
## 2 * x
```

`D()` is documented on the same page as `deriv()` (i.e. `?D`, `?deriv` bring you to the same page)

Apparently the `~` shortcut doesn't work with `D` , although you can use `quote()` rather than `expression()` to save a few keystrokes.

```
eval(D(quote(x^2), "x"),list(x=5))
## 10
```

Pulling the gradient expression out from the results of `deriv` is much nastier because it's not what the authors thought you would be trying to do.  `.grad` is not an attribute of the final result, it's a temporary variable used inside the function.  What the authors thought users would want in this case is the *numerical* value of the gradient when the expression is evaluated:

```
dd <- deriv(~ x^2,"x")
attr(eval(dd,list(x=5)),"gradient")
##       x
## [1,] 10
```

You can get the expression, but only by doing specific digging around in the body of the expression. `dd[[1]]` is the body of the expression. `dd[[1]][[4]]` is the fourth sub-expression:

```
dd[[1]][[4]]
## .grad[, "x"] <- 2 * x
```

and then we can extract the right-hand side (expressions are stored internally in prefix notation as `{operator,LHS,RHS}`:

```
dd[[1]][[4]][[3]]
## 2 * x
```

But this certainly seems to be the hard way, and furthermore will break if the R authors ever make a slight change to the internal structure of the expression returned by `deriv()`; this structure is not documented, therefore it is not guaranteed to stay the same ...

Comment: but nevertheless, how do I access these "dot notated elements", i.e. .value, .grad ? (for lack of knowledge of a better description)

Comment: is this the best way?    dx <- deriv(~ x^2,"x") ____   dx[[1]][[2]][[3]] ____
>x^2